# Create common custom visualforce page for standard entities

Tags: apex, visualforce, visualforce-component, standard-objects

I am trying to implement the `visualforce page` with in which I am showing phone number fields in detail page.

*For example* , For any specific contact / lead / opportunity / account / cases I am displaying the phone numbers in detail page and if user clicks on that phone number a new window will appear to do further operations.

In order to implement above solution I have created one custom `visualforce page` by setting `standard controller` to `Contact` (in case of contact) and used `extension` to fetch required phone fields based on some business logic.
Once I had created this custom `visualforce page` , I had to add it to the page layout of contact entity.

*code of contact's custom visualforce page*

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact" showHeader="false" sidebar="false" extensions="CommonExtension" standardStylesheets="true">
    <c:MYComponent phoneList="{!phones}" objName="{! objectName }" />
</apex:page>
```

Now, the problem is I need to create custom visualforce pages for all entities i.e. for account , lead , opportunity, case and add to the page layout which I feel is less optimized.

is there a way I can create common custom visualforce page ?

Comment: Since you want to use the page across different objects, you can't use `standardController`, you have to build a custom controller that will detect the object in question and check the object's phone fields, since of course they are different for each one.

Comment: If I use the custom controller then how would I able to add my custom page in page layout ?

Comment: @DavidCheng any suggestions on this ?

Comment: I missed the part about standard page layouts.  There's no way to do it in Classic with a single custom controller page, so you'll need a separate page with standard controller for each object.